# Innodb primary key advice

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, primary-key

We have a database table growing at a rate of ~20 million records per month, we're expecting this to double shortly.

The existing schema has a uuid4 as a primary key, and then two additional indexes on two other uuid4 columns. These columns are searched frequently for diagnosing issues. We can't change the UUID4 to something else as they are populated by an application we can't change.

We're planning on creating a new table and then back populating the data required from the old table into this one, fortunately, there's no real-time requirement for historic data.

The basic structure of the table is as follows

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Started | Date Time ( will always be increasing ) |
| app_id_one | uuid version 4 |
| app_id_two | uuid version 4 |
| app_id_three | uuid version 4 |

My questions are as follows:

1. As we don't control the uuid generation process does (started, app_id_one ) make sense as a primary key for the above structure, are there similar performance issues using uuid version 4 as the second column in a composite key?
2. We regularly have to search on app_id_two/app_id_three but I assume even have a secondary index of type uuid4 is bad for performance, so I am thinking we should also index these (started, app_id_two), (started, app_id_three )?
3. If we do option 2 this leads to a duplicate of the date time in the secondary index ( due to the chosen primary key ), space isn't too much of an issue we've got lots available on the servers, but would it be better just to generate a more suitable primary key instead?
4. We're considering populating this new table via a trigger as changing the application that populates the existing table is also not without its challenges. I'm worried about this adding to our already struggling write performance, but if I remove the two indexes from the existing table ( app_id_two / app_id_three ) I assume we'll get more than enough performance back from doing so?

Thank you!

Comment: *existing schema has a uuid4 as a primary key* Do you store UUIDs as strings or as BINARY? *We regularly have to search on uuid2/uuid4* Do you search for an equiation to some value, for a range matching, something else?

Comment: they are also being stored as strings currently, but I would look to store them in binary using the trigger. This is one of the problems with updating the code that's currently importing this table. We currently search with an exact match on UUID, but I am propsing that in future we will have to remember to search with a time range too

Comment: *I would look to store them in binary using the trigger.* Use generated column - this is more simple. Moreover, you may use virtual generated column and index by it - in this case generated value does not need in disk storage, but is used in the index for query improvement (and may be extracted from the index instead of recalculation if needed). *I am propsing that in future we will have to remember to search with a time range too* Time range is not relative to UUID.

Comment: I don't think uuid4 would benefit from a generated column as the values basically all random, so there's not much to extract unless I am missing something? Sorry i don't think I was clear, I'm proposing always searching with a time range so that the started,app_uuid_2 index can be used as an example

Comment: UUID-4 length is 32 (with delimiters - 36) symbols whereas compacting into BINARY results in 16 bytes length. This improve the searching (comparing) due two reasons - (1) shorter values == faster compare (2) binary collation during compare does not use codepage tables.

Comment: A old blog on [uuid ordering](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/)  because getting the fields the right way will help.

Comment: @danblack the uuids are V4 so doesn't help in this case, which is why i'm keen to know if started,uuid suffers the same fate as v4 would on it's own. My understanding makes me believe it'll be fine, as long as we're now too worried about the space/performance of a larger primary key

Comment: So, by "uuid4" you mean "uuid version 4"?  Only uuid ver 1 can be converted into a value that is (roughly) chronologically ordered.  This can benefit many types of queries.

Comment: Yes sorry, I should have made that clearer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, as the table (or index) grows, the performance approaches a minimum of one disk hit per lookup.

This is because UUIDs (other than a version 1 UUID with the bits suitably shuffled) are effectively "random".  That is whatever is in the buffer_pool cache is approaches being useless for the next lookup.

You seem to have 3 such indexes; this means that even inserting one row is threatening to require 3 disk hits!  20M new rows per month = 8 rows per second = upwards of 24 disk hits per second just for the insert traffic.  You could tackle this with a huge amount of RAM or by avoiding the 3 UUIDs.

Similarly, any `SELECT` that uses an `INDEX` starting with one of those uuids will incur 1 disk hit.

Keep in mind (for InnoDB) that the `PRIMARY KEY` is a big BTree with all the data, sorted by the PK.  And a secondary index is a smaller BTree with the key column(s) plus the PK's column(s).  So, some things stated about the PK and the seocndary key are interchangeable.

Of note,...  When looking up a row by a secondary key, two BTree lookups are performed, one per BTree involved.  If both are UUIDs that could mean 2 disk hits.  If you have `started`, and used composite indexes *starting* with `started`, *and* most queries reached for data around the same time, *then* you get "locality of reference benefits.  That is, everything might be cached and you won't need disk hits.

All of this leads to the beauty of using UUID, version 1, *and* rearrangin the bits so that the "time" part is in the high order bits.

(For your Q2 and Q3)  Assuming you now have

```
PRIMARY KEY(started),
INDEX(app_id_one),
INDEX(app_id_two),
INDEX(app_id_thre),
```

And assuming you are using InnoDB, then you already have `started` implicitly tacked onto the end of the 3 secondary indexes.  If, instead, you had

```
PRIMARY KEY(started),
INDEX(app_id_one),
INDEX(started, app_id_two),
INDEX(started, app_id_thre),
```

then the indexes would take exactly the same amount of space.  (OK building a BTreee leads to some unpredictables variations in "fragmentation", etc.)

Using a DATETIME as the PK is risky unless you are very sure you won't have any duplicates.  Changing the PK to INT or BIGINT (presumably AUTO_INCREMENT) would not change the principles here; just a slight difference in space needed.

pt-online-schema-change or gh-ost or MySQL 8.0 can change the existing table's indexes with minimal interruption.

I don't understand how you can change from the current `WHERE app_id_two = ...` to `WHERE started = ... AND app_id_two = ...`.  If you currently have `started` available, then just use it and get rid of the other columns??

Comment: Thank you! :) The application ids come from a third party app ( which is why we can't change to V1 ) and when we're doing the searches of app_id_two / app_id_three it's usually us manually running queries on this database to find faults which have occurred which is why we're able to use started.